# Can I one-shot an Electric or Thunder Wizzrobe with an elemental arrow?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

[Wizzrobes](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Wizzrobe#The_Legend_of_Zelda:_Breath_of_the_Wild)
come in elemental variants fire, ice, and electric. Interestingly, if you shoot a fire Wizzrobe with an [ice arrow](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Ice_Arrow), you will instantly kill it and the Wizzrobe drops their weapon. There is a similar idea with ice Wizzrobes; shoot it with a [fire arrow](https://zelda.fandom.com/wiki/Fire_Arrow) and you will instantly kill it.

I was wondering if there was an elemental equivalent to defeat the electric Wizzrobe in one shot? I am aware I could use an ancient arrow, however, the ancient arrow can one shot any common enemy (that is not a boss), so that does not really answer my question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

> Unlike Fire and Ice Wizzrobes, [Electric Wizzrobes] do not have any elemental weaknesses and a resistant to electricity.

[Source](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Electric_Wizzrobe#:%7E:text=Unlike%20Fire%20and%20Ice%20Wizzrobes,and%20a%20resistant%20to%20electricity.)

> Like Electric Wizzrobes, [Thunder Wizzrobes] lack an elemental weakness.

[Source](https://zelda-archive.fandom.com/wiki/Thunder_Wizzrobe)

The best way to deal with them is just aim for headshots. This will stun them momentarily, which you can use to chain headshots, and stunlocking them if done properly.

Answer (score 0):

No electric enemy has a elemental weakness but if you want to insta shot a electric wizzrobes you can use a ancient arrow

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! This doesn't actually answer the question.

Comment: The original question mentions the Ancient arrow and specifically says "that does not really answer my question".