# Do Electric and Thunder Wizzrobes have any weakness in TotK?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

A similar question was asked for Breath of the Wild:
[Can I one-shot an Electric or Thunder Wizzrobe with an elemental arrow?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/386175/87579)
And for that game the answer was "No".

Since elemental Wizzrobe are still present in the sequel, and both Fire/Ice Wizzrobes have carried their respective weaknesses...
Is there an elemental damage that can let me oneshot Electric Wizzrobe in Tears of the Kingdom?

Comment: I don't think so. However, you could technically one-shot it with a sufficiently powerful elemental attack that does 150+ (Electric) or 300+ (Thunder) damage, as in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403731/what-is-the-maximum-damage-for-a-single-attack-in-tears-of-the-kingdom/403732#403732).

Comment: @User23415 I know that. The fact is that elemental enemies can be defeated even throwing a fruit against them, I just wanted to know if electric-based ones have a weakness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, they don't have an elemental weakness. The only electric enemy that has an elemental weakness is the Shock Like's vulnerability to fire, but that is a Like Like trait, not an electric trait. While an attack that does 150+ (Electric Wizzrobe) or 300+ (Thunder Wizzrobe) damage is capable of one-shotting these enemies, electric enemies have no particular elemental weakness. See also [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/403731/what-is-the-maximum-damage-for-a-single-attack-in-tears-of-the-kingdom/403732#403732) for more on maximum damage.