# What is the maximum damage for a single attack in Tears of the Kingdom?

Tags: zelda-tears-of-the-kingdom

I've been plotting the demise of various strong monsters around Hyrule and was wondering what the maximum damage a single attack could do? This attack could be with a weapon, bow, or shield. Also, for this theoretical attack, you have unlimited resources, as well as bone proficiency armor and lv.3 attack up food. In addition, you can assume all bow shots are headshots. Ideally, you would be able to one-shot at least one of these creatures:

- Black Hinox, Stalnox, Sludge Like - 1,000 hp
- Flux Construct III, Stone Talus (Rare), Silver Moblin - 1,080 hp
- Queen Gibdo (1 phase) - 1,135 hp
- Silver Boss Bokoblin - 1,200 hp
- Molduga - 1,500 hp
- Lynel - 2,000 hp
- Blue-White Frox - 2,100 hp
- Demon King Ganondorf (Phase 1) - 2,500 hp
- Blue-Maned Lynel - 3,000 hp
- White-Maned Lynel - 4,000 hp
- Silver Lynel, Demon King Ganondorf (Phase 2) - 5,000 hp
- Demon King Ganondorf (Phase 3) - 6,000 hp
- Gleeok (all varieties) - 8,000 hp

Answer (score 7):

This is the best I can think of so far:

#### Gibdo Bone Sniping

- Greatest damage potential

- Uses Gibdo bone every shot
- Requires five headshots at once

- Weapon: Savage Lynel Bow
- Modifier: Five-Shot Burst
- Fusion Material: Gibdo Bone
- Relevant Buffs: Attack Up (Lv.3), Bone Attack Up (Bone Proficiency)

Calculation:

> [32 (base damage) + 40 (Gibdo Bone)] * 5 (Five-Shot Burst) * 2 (Headshots) * 1.8 (Bone Proficiency) * 1.5 (Attack Up) = 1944 damage

Assuming you can get the double damage from the headshot, this will one-hit kill Hinoxes, Stone Taluses, Flux Constructs, Moldugas, and silver enemies. In addition, this will instantly take any temple boss (other than Colgera) from full health to the second phase, or from the second phase to dead.

#### Breaking Point

- Quickly and reliably kill Lynels
- Easy to pull off
- Durability isn't used, so the weapon lasts indefinitely if carefully used.

- Requires rare pristine weapon with attack up +10 modifier
- Only works on Lynels

- Weapon: Royal Guard's Claymore✨
- Modifier: Attack Up +10
- Fusion Material: Molduga Jaw
- Relevant Buffs: Attack Up (Lv.3), Bone Attack Up (Bone Proficiency)

Note: The weapon must be on its last point of durability for this to work. This method requires attacking *the back* of the lynel, after it is stunned by a headshot.

Calculation:

> [39 (Base Weapon) + 10 (Modifier) + 32 (Molduga Jaw)] * 2 (Breaking Point) * 2 (Final hit) * 1.8 (Bone Proficiency) * 1.5 (Attack Up) * 20/19 (Hidden two-handed weapon buff) = 921 damage

This means that...

- A basic Lynel takes 3 hits to kill
- A Blue-Maned Lynel takes 4 hits to kill
- A White-Maned Lynel takes 5 hits to kill
- A Silver Lynel takes 6 hits to kill

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MI1SqGw9mL0&list=PLwGyU0mZTYHUB45gY82-eu4kxd1vGlxqo&index=24&pp=iAQB) for more details.

#### The Ultimate Sneakstrike Weapon

An extremely powerful and reliable sneakstrike weapon.

- Weapon: Eightfold Blade✨
- Modifier: Attack Up +10
- Fuse Material: Molduga Jaw/Gibdo Bone
- Relevant Buffs: Attack Up (Lv.3), Bone Attack Up (Bone Proficiency)

Calculation (Molduga Jaw):

> [15 (Base Weapon) + 10 (Modifier) + 32 (Molduga Jaw)] * 8 (Sneakstrike) * 2 (Improved Sneakstrike) * 1.8 (Bone Proficiency) * 1.5 (Attack Up) = 2463 damage

Calculation (Gibdo Bone):

> [15 (Base Weapon) + 10 (Modifier) + 40 (Gibdo Bone)] * 8 (Sneakstrike) * 2 (Improved Sneakstrike) * 1.8 (Bone Proficiency) * 1.5 (Attack Up) = 2808 damage

This will one-shot *any* enemy that is susceptible to sneakstrikes, as the most powerful enemy of this group is the Silver Boss Bokoblin, with 1200 hp. This might change if a Master Mode is added.

Note: Technically, you could achieve better results with a different weapon, such as a Lightscale Trident or Scimitar of the Seven with a Molduga Jaw. However, this is the best build I'm aware of that specifically uses an Eightfold Blade.

#### Smoke Rod

- Weapon: Any Forest Dweller's Weapon
- Modifier: Any
- Fuse Material: Puffshroom

This weapon can be used to create a cloud of smoke nearly anywhere, allowing you to perform sneakstrikes at will. See also Ultimate Sneakstrike Weapon.

Comment: Detailed and clear, +1. Also kudos to Austin John, love his videos.